# Updating many-to-many relation models in Prisma

Tags: sql, orm, prisma, cockroachdb

Given the following `prisma` model:

```
model User {
    user_id              String     @id @default(uuid())
    groups               Group[]    @relation("CreatedGroups")
    participating_groups Group[]    @relation("Participants") // -- keep track!
}

model Group {
    group_id      String   @id @default(uuid())
    participants  User[]   @relation("Participants")  // -- keep track too!
    creator_id    String
    creator       User     @relation("CreatedGroups", fields: [creator_id], references: [user_id])
}
```

Say i needed to add **one** participant into a group. By doing so, i'm updating 2 things:

- The `participants` array in the `Group` model. *(connecting the user)*
- The `participating_groups` array in the `User` model. *(connecting the group)*

Notice i've set a `@relation` at each field to mention it's related opposite at the other model.

My question is, how do i implement that in one single query, instead of updating both models seperately?

Comment: Updating one side of the relation should be sufficient. Maybe you need to share more code...

Comment: I'm trying to update both sides of the relation, so that the user could access the groups he's participating in, and groups could access their participants.
I pretty much shared all the code needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to update the relation from one side only? Is it working? If not, please share the code.